# How to turn off Roslyn Code Fixes in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

How can I turn off Roslyn Code Fixes in VS 2015?

It works correctly (with the latest Resharper 9.1.2), but still while it initializes it blocks navigation, I mean Home, End, Left, Right are delayed for 0.5 - 1.5 seconds. Also it seems to be fool the nav keys, now it's the dozenth times I find myself in the VS main menu, or an other source file just by pressing the 4 nav keys I've listed, I don't know how...

[image]

What I've tried so far:

1. Look for in the Tools/Options and search for 'Roslyn'
2. Context menu withing the Roslyn Code Fixes
3. Google
4. Native search in Stackoverflow

Probably I am missing something it would not be so hard...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your typing problems sounds suspiciously like this issue : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-445640 that appeared for VS2015 + R# they have some workarounds but not solution yet.

**Update**

From this tweet https://twitter.com/serjic/status/624202171060502528 it seem that they are working on a bugfix and that a good workaround exists :

> Turning off 'Do not show Visual Studio bulb' fixes typing issues in ReSharper 912. We are working on the hot fix.
>   [image: 'Do not show Visual Studio bulb' Option]

**Update 2**

They did a full blog post on it : [Critical Issue with ReSharper 9.1.2 in Visual Studio 2015 RTM: Workarounds and Estimates](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/07/23/critical-issue-with-resharper-9-1-2-in-visual-studio-2015-rtm-workarounds-and-estimates/)

Comment: Thanks. Although the effect is not clear (I unchecked the "Do not show" (twice negation) and now Roslyn is _not_ showing... I am trying to work and will be back with my experience

Comment: @g.pickardou In the betas roslyn bulb appeared along R# one and both worked with their kbd shortcuts, If the roslyn bulb doesn't appear maybe jetbrains got another bug in there. I don't have the bug but a colleague got and reported no more problems since he applied the workaround. Hope it works for you

Comment: Although it is completely solved the issue (thx again), actually does not answer _that_ question if one would like to turn off Roslyn code fixes _regardless_ of ReSharper. Some searcher may hope to get answer to _that_ question when surfing here.

Comment: @g.pickardou AFAIK disabling roslyn-provided analyzers is only possible at the project level for now via rulesets. There is no global settings. Multiple requests on Roslyn github exists for that but they are still open.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with R# 2016.1. I've checked the option, and the Roslyn icon and fixes are still displayed.